# How to transfer Netbeans Project into Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, netbeans

I have been using Netbeans for my java desktop application since few months. Now in the middle of the project, I want to switch over to Eclipse as the Netbeans once corrupted my GUI and I had to re-create several parts of the GUI and now it is displaying a compiler error as

```
code too large
private void initComponents() {
1 error
```

"code too large" is a strange error. My code which it is saying too large is just 10,000 lines long. I came to know first time that we couldn't develop long code in Netbeans :)

So instead of going into detail, I want to switch to Eclipse. I have never used it before. So could please tell me how to import my incompleted Netbeans project into eclipse.

Comment: 10 000 LINES LONG ? Don't you ever heard about refactoring ?

Comment: could you please tell me how to refactor my code?

Comment: remove reduant code, simply make it cleaner.

Comment: 10,000 lines of code doesn't necessarily mean that it's poorly written. I've been working on a cross platform game for a couple months and I reached over 8000 lines of code in the first month of it, and that was after essentially rewriting twice (decided to switch languages at that point, and having written all the code once already I had the best knowledge for being able to do heavy refactoring). Just saying....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont' know if there exists a plugin for that, but if you've used default Netbeans settings it's likely the GUI layout code and form files won't be compatible.

What I suggest you do is first refactor your existing code to eliminate Netbeans-specific features, as well as making it smaller, and working.

For GUI-stuff, you should create several classes and beans so that your main GUI file is much-much smaller. 10000 lines of GUI code is pretty much unmanageable.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do refactoring?

Comment: I have heard about it but don't know how to use refactoring.

Comment: Refactoring simply means rewriting your program in a different manner. The goal being to have simpler classes that encapsulate specific behavior rather than one gigantic class that does everything. For example, create a file for your menu, one for your main panel, one for your status bar, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your main concern is migrate the GUI builder stuff, not only your code. The latter would be no problem but I guess that the first one is difficult if not impossible. And furthermore, as far as I know there is no standard GUI builder application in eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

This should be resolved by spitting things up like others have said.

I just got a similar error and NetBeans was struggling with the code so I just tried to compile it on the command line with javac and it yelled at me with this same error. So this is not an IDE issue but a Java compiler issue.

If you get this error you probably auto-generated most of your code.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest thing to do would be to create a new project in eclipse and import the codebase from filesystem into the project. Eclipse has an option to import from filesystem.